# How do I install JDK 1.6 in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, java

When I upgrade to Mavericks, it uninstalls Java 1.6. I can install Java 7, but for some applications and development work, I still need access to Java 6. How can I reinstall Java 6 in Mavericks?

Apple docs generally recommend downloading Java directly from Oracle, but I don't see a Mac version listed on the Oracle download page for Java SE 6.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR

**Update**

I was able to install parts of Java 6, with an [Apple Support update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572). But Maven is still missing.

```
$ specs java os
Specs:

specs 0.7
https://github.com/mcandre/specs#readme

mvn --version
mvn not found

echo $CLASSPATH


echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/Home

javac -version
javac 1.6.0_65

java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep 'System Version'
      System Version: OS X 10.9 (13A603)
```

**Update 2**

I was able to install Maven with Homebrew:

```
$ brew install maven
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 11:22:22-0400)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.1.1/libexec
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: This maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-osx-10-9-mavericks

Answer (score 27):

You can download Java SE 6 for OS X from here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

For Maven support you can use brew (as stated above) or, if you don't want to install brew just for Maven support, you can download it directly from [maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). Here's the steps I took to get Maven setup on a fresh install of Mavericks:

```
curl -O http://apache.tradebit.com/pub/maven/maven-3/3.1.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/local
cd /usr/local
sudo tar -xf ~/apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin" >> .profile
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home" >> .profile
```

Comment: Does that include the JDK, with `javac` and `mvn`, or just the JRE?

Comment: @apennebaker I didn't think Maven was part of the JDK?

Comment: If you're using multiple version of the JDK on the Mac you'll want to know about `java_home`. e.g. `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)`

Comment: link is dead, fyi..

Answer (score 15):

This works on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan). I've used [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install JDK 1.6.0_65:

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java6
```

Comment: FYI, this downloads from the same apple support page [linked by Colin C.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106836/87027)

Comment: This proved to be of limited value as the end result was to stage the .pkg file, which was identical to directly downloading from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572.  Guess, it is handy for new users to brew cask. thanks for the suggestion all the same.

Comment: @arcseldon installing through Homebrew Cask makes it easy to update and uninstall JDK 1.6, though.

Comment: as of 2021, you use brew this way: brew tap homebrew/cask-versions; brew install --cask java6

Answer (score 13):

When I tried the accepted answer, I didn't see the new JDK 1.6 in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

I had to go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ search for "java", download the latest, and install that. Then the JDK 1.6 appeared.

Comment: Jave 6 will install at `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk` by default - the one you have downloaded from the developer site, is a developer version, and will - as you have noticed - install under `/Library/Java/...`

Comment: This answer gave me the missing piece to compiling JNI applications on Mavericks.  Most other discussions, particularly on SO, point people to `http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572` but that does not provide a JDK.  The information in this answer led me to the correct item.  So, thank you, very much.